# Intelligent Debt Ageing Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have some data in the format of;

```
Client Amt   Date
ABC Co £250  20/09/16
ABC Co £250  20/10/16
CDE Co £200  20/11/16
CDE Co £200  20/10/16
CDE Co £-200 20/09/16
FGH Co £600  01/01/16
FGH Co £-500 20/09/16
FGH Co £-50  20/10/16
FGH Co £100  20/11/16
```

I can pivot it like this easily;

```
Client Balance 0-29days 30-59days 60-89days 90days+
ABC Co £500    £0       £250      £250      £0
CDE Co £200    £200     £200      £-200     £0
FGH Co £100    £100     £-50      £-500     £600
IJK Co £-100   £100     £0        £0        £-200
```

But I need it to look like;

```
Client Balance 0-29days 30-59days 60-89days 90days+
ABC Co £500    £0       £250      £250      £0
CDE Co £200    £200     £0        £0        £0
FGH Co £100    £100     £0        £0        £50
IJK Co £-100   £0       £0        £0        £-100
```

The columns or "aging buckets" represent the age of a debit/credit. A single transaction will not occur in more than one bucket. If there are credits and debits they should be applied to eachother (starting with the oldest). So to elaborate on a few of the records...

CDE Co; The earliest transaction £-200 credit on 20/09 is balanced by the next transaction £200 debit on 20/10. This only leaves the £200 debit on 20/11 (hence the £200 debit in the 0-29days bucket).

FGH Co; The earliest transaction £600 debit on 01/01 is part paid by the 2 payments of £-500 (20/09) and £-50 (20/10) leaving £50 of debit in the 90days+ bucket and a more recent debit of £100 on 20/11 in the 0-29days bucket.

Is there a query/formula I can use to evaluate this? Or am I going to have to use a cursor?

Thanks

Comment: This would be MUCH easier if the source data wasn't pivoted.  I'm assuming you have a client, date, and a amount in a table somehwere and using date you pivot the data to the date ranges.  If you do this before the data is pivoted, it would be easier.

Comment: I suspect the data displayed is the result of a query.  Perhaps you could supply a sample of the transaction data

Comment: @xQbert that's correct. how would you approach it if the data wasn't pivoted?

Comment: you could use an window function something like `sum(amount) over (partition by client order by date ASC)` to generate a running total for a client and then only pivot the last total for the last day.   source table example (unpivoted) with some sample data in that format would be a good start.  but even then you've been showing nice round numbers -500 -100 +600.... I doubt they all break out that nicely so how do you want to handle partials?  Start with the unpivoted data from there you have a better chance of getting to the desired result.  Mock up some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @LeeTickett According to what I understand of your explanation, for ABC Co, should the 0-29days have 500 in it? (I am refer to the result you want it to look like)

Comment: @DVT no. What logic makes you think that?

Comment: And for ABC Co, 30-59days should also have 500 in it too?

Comment: Debit 250 on 20/09, debit 250 on 20/10. So the one on 20/10 should be rolled on?

Comment: The balances in each of the buckets are not rolling. i.e. if £250 has been outstanding for 60-89days and another £250 for 30-59days each of those buckets has £250 in. Does that help?

Comment: So for CDE Co, you have the -200 on 20/09, 200 on 20/10 and they cancel each other? What is the meaning of the columns in the original table?

Comment: The columns (buckets) are for the age of the debit/credit.

Comment: FGH Co should'n have a balance of £150? 600-500-50+100 = 700-550 = 150, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which seems to match your expected output. Note, it's a bit messy and you might be able to simplify the logic a bit, but at least it seems to work.

Link to working example: http://rextester.com/OWH97326

Note that this answer is adapted from a [solution to a slightly similar problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156192/109166) on dba.stackexchange.com. I was very impressed with the solution.

```
Create Table Debt (
    Client char(6),
    Amount money,
    [Date] date);

Insert Into Debt 
Values 
('ABC Co', 250,  Convert(date, '20/09/2016', 103)),
('ABC Co', 250,  Convert(date, '20/10/2016', 103)),
('CDE Co', 200,  Convert(date, '20/11/2016', 103)),
('CDE Co', 200,  Convert(date, '20/10/2016', 103)),
('CDE Co', -200, Convert(date, '20/09/2016', 103)),
('FGH Co', 600,  Convert(date, '01/01/2016', 103)),
('FGH Co', -500, Convert(date, '20/09/2016', 103)),
('FGH Co', -50,  Convert(date, '20/10/2016', 103)),
('FGH Co', 100,  Convert(date, '20/11/2016', 103));

With Grouping_cte As (
Select Client, Sum(ABS(Amount)) As Amount, 
    Case When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -30 Then '0-29 days'
         When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -60 Then '30-59 days'
         When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -90 Then '60-89 days'
         Else '90+ days' End As [Date],
    Case When Amount < 0 Then 'In' Else 'Out' End As [Type]
  From Debt
  Group By Client,
    Case When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -30 Then '0-29 days'
         When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -60 Then '30-59 days'
         When DateDiff(Day, GetDate(), [Date]) > -90 Then '60-89 days'
         Else '90+ days' End,
    Case When Amount < 0 Then 'In' Else 'Out' End),
RunningTotals_cte As (
Select Client, Amount, [Date], [Type],
    Sum(Amount) Over (Partition By Client, [Type] Order By [Date] Desc) - Amount As RunningTotalFrom,
    Sum(Amount) Over (Partition By Client, [Type] Order By [Date] Desc) As RunningTotalTo
  From Grouping_cte),
Allocated_cte As (
Select Outs.Client, Outs.Date, Outs.Amount + IsNull(Sum(x.borrowed_qty),0) As AdjustedAmount
  From (Select * From RunningTotals_cte Where [Type] = 'Out') As Outs
  Left Join (Select * From RunningTotals_cte Where [Type] = 'In') As Ins
    On Ins.RunningTotalFrom < Outs.RunningTotalTo
    And Outs.RunningTotalFrom < Ins.RunningTotalTo
    And Ins.Client = Outs.Client
  Cross Apply (
      Select Case When ins.RunningTotalTo < Outs.RunningTotalTo Then Case When ins.RunningTotalFrom > Outs.RunningTotalFrom  Then -1 * Ins.Amount
                                                                          Else -1 * (Ins.RunningTotalTo - Outs.RunningTotalFrom) End
                  Else Case When Outs.RunningTotalFrom > Ins.RunningTotalFrom Then Outs.Amount
                            Else -1 * (Outs.RunningTotalTo - Ins.RunningTotalFrom) End End) As x (borrowed_qty)
  Group By Outs.Client, Outs.Date, Outs.Amount)
--Select * From Allocated_cte;

Select Client,
    Sum(AdjustedAmount) As Balance,
    Sum(iif([Date] = '0-29 days', AdjustedAmount, Null)) As [0-29 days],
    Sum(iif([Date] = '30-59 days', AdjustedAmount, Null)) As [30-59 days],
    Sum(iif([Date] = '60-89 days', AdjustedAmount, Null)) As [60-89 days],
    Sum(iif([Date] = '90+ days', AdjustedAmount, Null)) As [90+ days]
  From Allocated_cte
  Group By Client;
```

Answer (score 2):

Link Showing it working : http://rextester.com/MLFE98410

I was curious which was was easier logically the recursive cte is a bit easier but sill has some of the same hurdles. Note I added yet 1 more test case here too.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Client CHAR(6), AMT INT, Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/09/20')
,('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/11/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',-200,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',600 ,'2016/01/01')
,('FGH Co',-500,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',-50 ,'2016/10/20')
,('FGH Co',100 ,'2016/11/20')
,('IJK Co',-100 ,'2016/01/01')
,('IJK Co',-100 ,'2016/09/20')
,('LMN Co',-200 ,'2016/01/01')
,('LMN Co', 50 ,'2016/06/10')
,('LMN Co',-100 ,'2016/09/20')

;WITH cteRowNumbers AS (
    SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       Client
       ,CurrentBalance = SUM(AMT)
       ,Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       ,Amt = CAST(0 AS INT)
       ,RemainingBalance = SUM(Amt)
       ,AttributedAmt = 0
       ,RowNumber = CAST(0 AS BIGINT)
    FROM
       @Table
    GROUP BY
       Client

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       r.Client
       ,r.CurrentBalance
       ,c.Date
       ,c.AMT
       ,CASE WHEN SIGN(r.CurrentBalance) = SIGN(c.AMT) THEN r.CurrentBalance - c.AMT ELSE r.RemainingBalance END
       ,CASE
          WHEN SIGN(r.CurrentBalance) <> SIGN(c.AMT) THEN 0
          WHEN ABS(r.RemainingBalance) < ABS(c.AMT) THEN r.RemainingBalance
          ELSE c.AMT END
       ,c.RowNumber
    FROM
       cteRecursive r
       INNER JOIN cteRowNumbers c
       ON r.Client = c.Client
       AND r.RowNumber + 1 = c.RowNumber
    WHERE
       SIGN(r.RemainingBalance) = SIGN(r.CurrentBalance)
)

, ctePrepared AS (
    SELECT
       Client
       ,CurrentBalance
       ,DateGroup = CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 29 THEN '0-29days'
          WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '30-59days'
          WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '60-89days'
          WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) >= 90 THEN '90days+'
              ELSE 'Unknown Error'
       END
       ,AttributedAmt
    FROM
       cteRecursive
    WHERE
       RowNumber > 0
       AND AttributedAmt <> 0
)

SELECT *
FROM
    ctePrepared c
    PIVOT (
       SUM(AttributedAmt)
       FOR DateGroup IN ([0-29days],[30-59days],[60-89days],[90days+])
    ) pvt
ORDER BY
    Client
```

Results

```
Client  CurrentBalance  0-29days    30-59days   60-89days   90days+
ABC Co  500            NULL         250         250         NULL
CDE Co  200            200          NULL        NULL         NULL
FGH Co  150            100          NULL        NULL         50
IJK Co  -200             NULL        NULL   -100         -100
LMN Co  -250             NULL        NULL   -100         -150
```

Answer (score 1):

Link to Working Example: http://rextester.com/NAAUE88941

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Client CHAR(6), AMT INT, Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/09/20')
,('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/11/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',-200,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',600 ,'2016/01/01')
,('FGH Co',-500,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',-50 ,'2016/10/20')
,('FGH Co',100 ,'2016/11/20')
,('IJK Co',-100 ,'2016/01/01')
,('IJK Co',-100 ,'2016/09/20')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       Client
       ,Date
       ,AMT
       ,CurrentBalance = SUM(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY Client)
       ,BackwardsRunningTotal = SUM(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC)
       ,CurrentBalanceMinusBackwardsRunningTotal = SUM(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY Client) - SUM(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC)
       ,DateGroup = CASE
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 29 THEN '0-29days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '30-59days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '60-89days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date,GETDATE()) >= 90 THEN '90days+'
             ELSE 'Unknown Error'
       END
       ,BalanceAtTime = SUM(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date)
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteWhenCurrentBalanceIsMet AS (
    SELECT
       Client
       ,MaxDate = MAX(DATE)
    FROM
       cte
    WHERE
       CurrentBalanceMinusBackwardsRunningTotal = 0
    GROUP BY
       Client
)

, cteAgedDebtPrepared AS (
    SELECT
       c.Client
       ,Balance = c.CurrentBalance
       ,c.DateGroup
       ,Amt = CASE
          WHEN CurrentBalanceMinusBackwardsRunningTotal = 0
          THEN ISNULL(LAG(CurrentBalanceMinusBackwardsRunningTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Client ORDER BY Date DESC),AMT)
          ELSE AMT
       END
    FROM
       cteWhenCurrentBalanceIsMet m
       INNER JOIN cte c
       ON m.Client = c.Client
       AND m.MaxDate <= c.Date
       AND SIGN(c.AMT) = SIGN(c.CurrentBalance)
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteAgedDebtPrepared
    PIVOT (
       SUM(Amt)
       FOR DateGroup IN ([0-29days],[30-59days],[60-89days],[90days+])
    ) pvt
ORDER BY
    Client
```

Definitely was a challenging question it was more so because even though you are saying you are looking at aged Debt you actually show both Aged Debt and Aged Credit in your Pivot Table.  I think it would be easier to do in a Recursive CTE but I wanted more of a set based operation so above is what I have come up with and it works for all of your test cases.  Note I did add one where the net was a Credit.

General Steps

- Determine Current Balance
- A Backwards Running Total (e.g. SUM(AMT) From most current date to the oldest date)
- Subtract the Backwards Running Total From Current Balance to determine at which point the balance was last 0 and then get the `MAX(date)` at which that occured
- Do a self join to grab all of the records `>=` that `MAX(date)` that are the same `SIGN()`, e.g. when balance is positive then amt must be positive or reverse negative and negative for credits.  The reason it has to be the same SIGN() is that the inverse would actually affect the balance in the opposite direction we are looking for.
- Figure Out The remainder of the Debt or Credit that needs to be attributed to the first Row when the balance was last 0 by looking at the previous row or assigning the AMT
- Pivot As Desired

the results:

```
Client  Balance 0-29days    30-59days   60-89days   90days+
ABC Co  500     NULL        250         250         NULL
CDE Co  200     200         NULL        NULL        NULL
FGH Co  150     100         NULL        NULL        50
IJK Co  -200    NULL        NULL        -100        -100
```

Note for My IJK example I had two credits of -100 each.

Comment: Amazing, thank you, I will need to spend a little time with it but looks thorough!

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103444/sql-how-to-split-quantity-into-multiple-rows-based-on-quantity-on-target-source/40746522#40746522) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676520/complex-sql-update-on-2-interdependent-tables/40743522#40743522) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023370/sql-first-in-first-out-loyalty-point/40748138#40748138)

You need to explode debits and credits to single units and then couple them chronologically, and filter away the matching rows, then you can age them per periods.

Just pivot the sum up for each period.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Client CHAR(6), AMT INT, Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/09/20')
,('ABC Co',250 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/11/20')
,('CDE Co',200 ,'2016/10/20')
,('CDE Co',-200,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',600 ,'2016/01/01')
,('FGH Co',-500,'2016/09/20')
,('FGH Co',-50 ,'2016/10/20')
,('FGH Co',100 ,'2016/11/20')
,('IJK Co',-200 ,'2016/01/01')
,('IJK Co',100 ,'2016/09/20')
```

For FN_NUMBERS(n), it is a tally table, look at other answers I have linked above to get an example or google it.

```
;with
m as (select * from @Table),
e as (select * from m where AMT>0),
r as (select * from m where AMT<0),
ex as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Client order by [date] ) rn, 1 q
    from e
    join FN_NUMBERS(1000) on N<= e.AMT
),
rx as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Client order by [date] ) rn, 1 q
    from r
    join FN_NUMBERS(1000) on N<= -r.AMT
),
j as (
select 
    isnull(ex.Client, rx.Client) Client, 
    (datediff(DAY, ISNULL(ex.[Date],rx.[Date]), GETDATE()) / 30) dd,
    (isnull(ex.q,0) - isnull(rx.q,0)) q
from ex
full join rx on ex.Client = rx.Client and ex.rn = rx.rn 
where ex.Client is null or  rx.Client is null
),
mm as (
    select j.Client, j.q, isnull(x.n,99) n
    from j
    left join (values (0),(1),(2)) x (n) on dd=n
),
b as (
    select Client, SUM(AMT) balance
    from m
    group by Client
),
p as (
    select b.*, p.[0] as [0-12days], p.[1] as [30-59days], p.[2] as [60-89days], p.[99] as [90days+]
    from mm
    pivot (sum(q) for n in ([0],[1],[2],[99])) p
    left join b on p.Client = b.Client
)
select *
from p
order by 1
```

perfect output

```
Client  balance 0-12days    30-59days   60-89days   90days+
ABC Co  500     NULL        250         250         NULL
CDE Co  200     200         NULL        NULL        NULL
FGH Co  150     100         NULL        NULL        50
IJK Co  -100    NULL        NULL        NULL        -100
```

bye

Answer (score -1):

If you only need the data in the format you have provided and what you say in the comments about having an unpivoted base table with this data in, the query is very simple:

```
declare @t table(PaymentDate date
                ,Client nvarchar(50)
                ,Amount decimal(10,2)
                );
insert into @t values
 ('20160920','ABC Co',250),('20161020','ABC Co',250  ),('20161020','CDE Co',200  ),('20161020','CDE Co',200  ),('20160920','CDE Co',-200 ),('20160101','FGH Co',600  ),('20160920','FGH Co',-500 ),('20161020','FGH Co',-100 ),('20161120','FGH Co',100  );

declare @ReportDate date = getdate();

select Client

        -- Data aggregated by each period
        ,sum(Amount) as ClientBalance
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate between dateadd(d,-29,@ReportDate) and @ReportDate then Amount else 0 end) as [0-29 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate between dateadd(d,-59,@ReportDate) and dateadd(d,-30,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [30-59 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate between dateadd(d,-89,@ReportDate) and dateadd(d,-60,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [60-89 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate <= dateadd(d,-90,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [90+ Days]

        ,'' as [ ]

        -- Data aggregated as a rolling periodic balance
        ,sum(Amount) as ClientBalance
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate <= @ReportDate then Amount else 0 end) as [0-29 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate <= dateadd(d,-30,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [30-59 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate <= dateadd(d,-60,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [60-89 Days]
        ,sum(case when PaymentDate <= dateadd(d,-90,@ReportDate) then Amount else 0 end) as [90+ Days]
from @t
group by Client
order by Client;
```

Comment: Either i'm missing something or your missing something. Your query looks like what i'm currently using to pivot the data. The result of which looks like my first example... but I need it to look like my second example?

Comment: @LeeTickett  Could you kindly provide your source data and the logic behind the first pivot?  Your question is lacking basic information.  What is meant by each column?  My code above currently gives you the running balance at each date window as well as the current.  What is it you are actually after?

Comment: Currently my query just gives the balance in each ageing bucket (same as yours I believe). But If you look at my example you can see that records with credits and debits actually need some further work; CDE Co for example have a credit balance in the 60-89days bucket and debit balance in 30-59days so these can be applied to eachother leaving just the balance in 0-29days. I will add an example of source data to the original question.

Comment: @LeeTickett  What is the logic that states one date window should be applied to another though?  Certainly one that is in the future?  Are you just after the current balance at each window end, taking into account all transactions up to that point?

Comment: The idea is that older debit/credits would be balanced first. For example if you had a £100 credit (with any age), a £100 debit 60days and another £100 30days you would apply the £100 credit to the £100 60days. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @LeeTickett  So a running total stretching back across all prior transactions?

Comment: @LeeTickett  I have edited my answer to have both logical aggregations of your transactional data.  One of those must be doing what you are after, or you are simply after some nonsensical grouping of periodic values based on implicit rules that are only sometimes enforced.

Comment: It's not nonsensical nor or is it only sometimes enforced I assure you. Perhaps re-read my explanation and re-look at the examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128718/discussion-between-iamdave-and-lee-tickett).